# Hide tab bar when keyboard opens react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I want to hide my tabBar on a screen when my keyboard opens.I have already tried changing my AndroidManifest.xml file.By changing `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">` to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">` my screen tabBar hides when keyboard opens but the issues is my now my text Input is overlapping with my keyboard and I have also tried KeyboardAvoidingView but it is not working because when you change your XML file it also affects your other app components.So tell me how can i hide my tabBar when keyboard opens without changing my XML file.

Answer (score 3):

The current way to do it is by using `tabBarHideOnKeyboard` and setting it to `true` or `false`, you can use it on a specific screen.

```
 <Tab.Screen
    options={{
      ...
      tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
      ...
    }}
    ...
 />
```

or in the Navigator for all the screens like so:

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    ...
    tabBarHideOnKeyboard:true,
    ...
  }}
>
```

Check the official documentation here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbarhideonkeyboard

Answer (score 2):

**You don't need to use Keyboard listeners and change your AndroidManifest.xml file you  can solve this issue by just adding this tabBarOptions props :**

```
 <Tab.Navigator

 tabBarOptions={{

keyboardHidesTabBar: true,

 }}>

 </Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer by Muhammad Haidar is great, but now depreacted.

The way to write it is the following:

```
<Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
        tabBarStyle: [{ display: "flex" }, null]
    }}
>
```